Is there a way to customize the Label() of an ApplicationToken in SwifttUI?
So basically I just cant get it to work to change the look of the Label() of an Application Token of Apples Screen Time API.
I have tried multiple things for the:
Label(ApplicationToken)
this for example does scale it but I cant customize the text for example of the Label:
Label(ApplicationToken)
.scaleEffect(1.5)
I tried dynamic Type Size, Font, Fontweight and also a custom LabelStyle but I just cant get it to work.
Please help me I am mostly trying to change the look of the title of the Label() for example changing the size and font weight would be great!
